# JavaScript - Get object / call function inside function's return statement

Tags: javascript

I have a weird situation, I'm working with a 3rd party API and I can use JavaScript but all my code has to be a return function in order for it to work, here is how my app looks like, it gets plugged into their system:

### app.js

```
(function() {
    var myVar1 = null;
    var globalFunction = function(){
       alert('TEST');
    }
    return {
        test: null,
        requests: {
        },
        events: {
            'app.activated': 'initApp'
        },
        insideFunction: function(item){
            //some code
        },
        initApp:function(){
            //some code
            //I can set the gobal variables using varName = Value
            //I can set the return variables using this.varName = Value
            //I can call the return functions using this.insideFunction()
            //the entire app is basically run from inside 'return'
        }
    };
}());
```

I can access the global vars / function from inside the return, but how can I do it vice-versa? I need to call insideFunction from the globalFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the object you're returning to a variable before returning it.

```
var api = {
    test: null,
    ...
};
var globalFunction = function() {
    api.insideFunction();
};

return api;
```

Comment: Thanks, due to the nature of the API, anything global carries over to other tickets so I was under the impression if I did this then "api" would be carried over with all values, I still need to do some testing but this may not be the case when done this way. Now for the second part, I need to be able to call them back and forth, so with this setup I can call api vars from global but when I tried it the other way it says global is undefined (probably because it comes after in load order), so how can I get around this issue?

Comment: @Mankind1023 `global` should be `undefined` since you haven't defined it but accessing `globalFunction` should work perfectly, assuming you aren't calling before it's defined.